# First steps in Neo4j

Tags: java, json, neo4j

I am currently involved in a project where I need to build a remote neo4j server for adding some ego-networks (with just a few of nodes and relationships).

I've been using this documentation: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server-java-rest-client-example.html

However, I do not find how to create unique nodes (specifying an attribute as id) and I would like to know if it is also possible to make some queries to the REST API via url (solr style).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j has a REST API - see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api.html for the documentation.

Nodes can be unique per-index (meaning, if you index a property, you can enforce only one node existing for that property) - see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-unique-indexes.html for the documentation to do this via the REST API.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to get the JSON responses via web browser but I'm finally using curl and editing the headers of the requests.

I see how to create unique nodes. If I want to create relationship sbetween them, how can specify the start&end nodes of a relatinship with the key/value instead of the uri of the corresponding nodes?

Source: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-unique-indexes.html#rest-api-create-a-unique-relationship-in-an-index

Comment: Use cypher for that, `start n1=node:indexname(key='value'), n2=node:indexname(key='value2') create n1-[:CONNECT]->n2`